# Adding app shell item to Windows Device notification dialog

Tags: shell, delphi, notifications, device

I don't really know what they're called, but I'm referring to the window that pops up when you connect, lets say, a thumb drive.

These notification dialogs have a list of application that you can choose to open in order to do some actions regarding that device. (what are those notification dialogs called? I couldn't find anything about it)

**The question:**
How do I add such an item to those notification dialogs?

My guess is that a regkey is added.

Comment: Is it the "open with" dialog  or the special Windows 8.x Dialog that shows up when new programs are installed

Comment: Yes, I think that's the one.

Comment: Sorry I misread your comment, I believe it's the "open with" dialog.

Comment: [How to Include an Application in the Open With Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127445.aspx)

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you, not exactly what I needed, but still useful. The link you posted is about file-types, I am not looking for file-types, I'm looking for device connection. I found this which seems to be on the right track: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127445(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @vaid: That is the same page I gave you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau oh, sorry about that I must've clicked something else then.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the "Open With" dialog from the registry. It is located here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
```

Then you open the folder with your extention and then the "OpenWith" folder. Then add or remove your program.

The whole process are described in details here:

[Add or Remove Programs in the Open With Menu From the Registry](http://www.technorms.com/26760/add-remove-programs-open-menu-registry)